# Can't put math.h in a namespace

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm doing some cross platform development, and I ran across another weird problem..

```
namespace Math 
{
    #include <math.h>
}
```

This is what I am trying to do. It works fine on iOS, but on Android everything inside math.h is not a member of Math when I try to compile it. After some trial an error I found out that the ndk doesn't put the stuff in math.h in the namespace Math, as the functions do exist without the Math:: prefix. The big problem is that some functions in math.h clash with my own convenience functions. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you can't place `<math.h>` in it's own namespace, why not place your code within a namespace and when you need to call stuff from `<math.h>`, use `::foo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `<cmath>`? it puts everything in `std::` (in C++11).

Comment: This option is less painful than the others. Thanks :)

Comment: In C++11 <cmath> is allowed to also put things in the global namespace, fouling up the OP's "convenience functions" in the global namespace. And the reason why C++11 allows that is that C++ implementations did that anyway... :-( I.e., this solution makes it easy to refer to the standard functions, but it may still be difficult to refer to the OP's global namespace convenience functions.

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't try to put any system headers into a different namespace.  The solution, as painful as it may be at this point in development, is to put all of your code into its own namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put your convenience functions in the global namespace.

Don't try to wrap `math.h` in a namespace.

There, all’OK now.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Probably something else includes `math.h` earlier in the preprocessor "pipeline". C includes check whether the sane include has been included earlier. In this case, the check `#ifndef MATH_H` resulted in excluding the whole file. Try placing your include with the namespace at the beginning of your `.c` files.